# Oracle Forms Not Showing Messages

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to show messages in my form. I wrote them in an item's 'KEY-NEXT-ITEM' trigger.

```
MESSAGE ('You can not write this!');
MESSAGE ('You can not write this!');
```

But form is not showing this messages. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the reason! I did'nt choose console window of my form. When I chose a console window, messages appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Messages *do* work.

`KEY-NEXT-ITEM` trigger is probably not the best choice. It fires if you press TAB or ENTER keys on the keyboard to navigate out of the item. If you, for example, clicked with a mouse and left the item, then this trigger won't fire. A better choice is `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger so I'd suggest you try it. If it doesn't help, describe the problem again, providing some more details.

Comment: f I press TAB or ENTER keys, it doesn't show messages. Also when I used WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM, it didn't show. Now I use a "WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED" trigger (it contains only messages) and when I press related button it doesn't show messages.

Comment: So, whatever you do, a message doesn't appear? Not even in form's status line (at the bottom of the form window)?

Comment: Yes, even Status line, messages don't appear. It May be related "system.message_level" variable.

Comment: Maybe. Did you change it? By default, it is set to 0, i.e. as if you ran `:system.message_level := 0;`. If you set it to another value, search for it, check *why* you did that and - if possible - reset it to 0 (after you've done what you're doing while setting it to a higher value).

Comment: I reset it to 0 and it didn't appear :/

Comment: That's strange. Try to create a brand new simple form which will have a button and a `message` call in the WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger. See what happens.

Comment: in other forms messages appear. This problem is for just one form.

Comment: Well, then you'll have to debug that form. I'm afraid that there's nothing much we can do for you.

Comment: I got the reason! I did'nt choose console window of my form. When I chose a console window, messages appeared. Thank you for all your help.